# How to get the map between disk volume label and drive in python

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to get the map between disk volume and drive in python but failed in any SO thread. It's quite easy to implement it in java, as the sample below:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
public class Test{

    public void listMap(){
        File[] files = File.listRoots();
        System.out.println("The map between volume label and drive is: " );
        for(File file: files){
            String theMap = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemDisplayName(file);
            System.out.println(theMap);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.listMap();
    }
}
```

The map between volume label and drive is:

```
2008x64 (C:)
FlashDisk (E:)
```

If the map is there, it's quite easy to get drive "C:" based on the volume label "(2008x64)" and vice versa.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the `win32api` `GetVolumeInformation` method.

```
In [3]: win32api.GetVolumeInformation('c:\\')
Out[3]: ('', -697410715, 255, 65471231, 'NTFS')
```

Where '' would be the label (except my c drive is unlabeled).

Comment: @a p. No, I'm afraid it's not what I want. There is no volume label in the out put. The volume label is actually the "name" of the partition.

Comment: A "volume label" is not at all "the name of a partition." The name of a partition is a user-assigned 'label' that has nothing to do with a "volume label." Volume labels are either `msdos` or `gpt`. I know this is an old question but this is not good information on SO.